# Ionic 3 and Azure AD B2C implementation

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3, azure-active-directory

Has anyone tried using Azure AD B2C with Ionic 3.

What is the best method to implement a login page? 
Is there any plugin or libraries?
Or Should i simple use the inbrowser app and preform a login page via the webpage?

Thank You

Comment: Have you used the Azure sample for this? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-angular2.4-spa

Comment: Thanks I will try that out. I also found the following,https://www.raddy.co.uk/blog/ionic-3-msadal/